# Div not showing, source included

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can anyone tell me why my

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>

<pre id="linksHolder"></pre>
```

are not showing up here:

Relevent Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWxYd/5/ (credits to Matt McDonald)

-Should work for the first image under "Rage Faces" tab.

Bonus: Can you tell me how to get rid of the background changer without getting rid of the image opacity changer.

Comment: But they *are* showing up, when the dark boxes are clicked ...

Comment: They are showing up here! (chrome, mac osx)

Comment: The images being added into the table are not being found.  Like, "rage1_s.png" - the URL you're using is apparently wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason they arent showing? rage1m.png is def there, plus the links should show anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why (only checked it quickly with Firebug), but it looks like a css thing: If you declare a position for "linksHolder" and "tableHolder", they are visible.

```
eg.

#tableHolder {position: relative}
```